# object names gets duplicated when moving from a collection to another

Tags: objects, collections

in the resent versions of blender I got this weird behavior when I try to move an object to another collection it's name gets duplicated the object it self remains one but with two names in two different collection ,well I get away from this by renaming the object but is their a reason for this or a way to prevent it from happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem when cutting and pasting collections from one blend file to another. I was getting duplicate entries, but greyed out in the outliner.

Appending one collection at a time into a new file solved my problem. Don't know whether it will work in your case...